# Kubuntu 15.04 Clipboard is behaving strangely

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, clipboard

Ever since updating to Kubuntu 15.04, my clipboard hasn't been working properly. Sometimes when quickly trying to copy and paste an URL it doesn't copy and I end up accidentally pasting the last thing in my clipboard. This only happens some of the time though. My workaround is to hit ctrl+c 3-4 times, it seems it just doesn't 'take' sometimes.

My second issue is, for example, right now I clearly have something in the clipboard yet I can't paste. ctrl+v does nothing and when I right click, the paste icon is greyed out. Copying something new fixes that.

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Sounds like a bug, would be useful to report to the devs https://bugs.kde.org/