# Kubuntu 16.04 LTS and Phpstorm 2016.3 - Clipboard Issue - cannot paste

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, openjdk, clipboard, intellij

After upgrading my working Kubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS a few days ago everything went fine.

But now I experienced that sometimes (I cannot even reproduce or find any rule for it) my clipboard hits and misses (e.g. sometimes I cannot paste values).
Worst experience is with Intellij's PHPStorm. I am simply not able in 90% of the time (no matter what the source of the copy is) to paste any texts.

Only thing I found on the net was the tip to use the bundled OpenJDK which I do to my understanding:

PhpStorm 2016.3.2

Build #PS-163.10504.2, built on December 20, 2016

JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 amd64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

As I do not even know where to start to look out for this issue, can you please help me?

A couple of further info:

1. I don't close any windows before I paste
2. to my understanding I only have the Kubuntu 16.04 clipboard(s) installed
3. there is no remote connection or anything involved
4. anything happens locally with my standard user

**UPDATE**

5. I checked as well any shortcut properties but nothing seems overwritten.
6. 2nd Linux clipboard (mark a text and paste with middle mouse button) seems to work so far, issue seems to be with CTRL-C/V CTRL-SHIFT-C/V.

Only question here which comes close to mine but got no solution is: [Kubuntu 15.04 Clipboard is behaving strangely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655312/kubuntu-15-04-clipboard-is-behaving-strangely)

Please help, it's so annoying :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue while KeePass2 running in mono.

This did trick for me:

```
sudo apt-get install xsel:i386
```

Comment: Indeed! This did it - thanks a lot. Quite sure this isn't a real solution but as long as it's working.